# Jenkins CI clang scan-build with prefix environment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins CI on Mac Server with clang scan-build plugin.
After I build an iOS app, and run `scan-build` command, Then the graph will appear on right corner. When I click the edge on the graph, page says "404 Not found" because of the prefix `/jenkins` is not in URL. How can I fix this issue and it this a bug of this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the settings of `Jenkins Location` in the `Manage Jenkins`tool, under `Configure System`.

This should be set to the base URL for your Jenkins server, which should include `/jenkins/` according to your post.   Make sure to leave the trailing slash **in** the URL.

Comment: I set to the base URL includes ``/jenkins/`` , but it still doesn't work.